# How to fix function/symbol 'pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions' error

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, django-views

I have deployed a Django project using Apache2, everything is working fine except for weazyprint which creates PDF file for forms. The pdf was working fine in testing and local host.

Now everytime I access the pdf it is showing this error:

```
FileNotFoundError at /business_plan/businessplan/admin/info/2/pdf/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ahesham/Portfolio/static\\css\\report.css'
```

I have tried to change the `\` and adding it twice but it didn't work
here is the views.py

```
def admin_order_pdf(request, info_id):
    info = get_object_or_404(Info, id=info_id)
    html = render_to_string('businessplan/pdf.html', {'info': info})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="order_{}.pdf"'.format(
        Info.id)
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(response,
                                           stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '\css\\report.css')], presentational_hints=True)
    return response
```

The error is comming from this `\css\\report.css` knowing that the report.css file is in the static folder and all css and js of the deplyed site is working perfectly fine and I tried `python manage.py collectstatic` did not work.

I am not sure exactly why is the error showing if it is because of ubunto or django views.

**Update:**

I have tried changing the location to be as following:

```
stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '/css/report.css')], presentational_hints=True)
```

This is the error that appeared

```
function/symbol 'pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions' not found in library 'libpango-1.0.so.0': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions
```

So I have searched for the solution and I tried to download this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0
```

and also tried:

```
install libpango1.0-dev
```

but still nothing changed it wouldn't work getting the same error.

I have also tried replacing static directory with static root as the project is deployed buy i got the same error `function/symbol 'pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions'`  the following:

```
stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/css/report.css')]
```

This is the settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#if DEBUG:
#    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
#else:
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static' )]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Disk - Apache2 Server

**My question:**
What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Please let me know if additional information required to help fix this error.

Any feedback will be highly appreciated if there are other ways to display PDF in Django admin

Comment: Replace `settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '/css/report.css'` with `os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], '/css/report.css')`. Also, what's the pango library and API version you're using?

Comment: pango-view (pango) 1.40.14

Comment: According to their docs, https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/method.Context.set_round_glyph_positions.html, the method set_round_glyph_positions is available since 1.44. Try upgrading it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had also faced the same error

> 'pango_context_set_round_glyph_positions' not found in library

i think you must be using weasyprint version 53.0 which requires pango version 1.44.0+

downgrading the weasyprint version to 52.5 solved my issue.because this does not require recent version of pango.

you can also check this https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1384

Comment: You can't seem to use the latest pango version in the base docker image for `python:3.8.5-slim-buster` which is listed in the github issue thread as a Debian issue. For now downgrading WeasyPrint in requirements.txt was the only way I could fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command to downgrade weasyprint to version 52.5.

***$ python -m pip install WeasyPrint==52.5***

Answer (score -7):

Probably Weasyprint was not downloaded properly:

try:

```
pip install django-weasyprint
```

source: https://pypi.org/project/django-weasyprint/